# openCV Error in cvtColor function: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

Tags: python, opencv

I want to simply load a video file, convert it to grayscale and the display it. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cars.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #print frame.shape   


    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The video plays in grayscale till the end. Then it freezes and the window becomes Not Responding and I get the following error in the terminal:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/clive/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3737
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cap.py", line 13, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/clive/Downloads/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I uncommented the statement print frame.shape. It keeps printing 720,1028,3. But after the video plays till the end, freezes and after a while it closes and it returns

```
print frame.shape   
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I understand that this assertion failure massage usually means that I'm trying to convert an empty image. I added a check for empty image before starting to process it using the if(ret): statement. (Any other way of doing it??)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cars.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #print frame.shape   

    if(ret): #if cam read is successfull
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This time the video plays till the end and the window still freezes and closes after a few seconds. This time I don't get any error. But why does the window freeze? How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe the `cap.release()` takes some time to complete. Is the window still freezing if you swap the two lines at the end ?

Comment: @Arnaud P Yes it does

Comment: Ok. As a final wild guess: if you are multi-threading, opencv image display doesn't do well if it's not run on the main thread.

Comment: @Arnaud P What is multi-threading? How do I 'run on the main thread'?

Comment: [Multithreading on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading), basically it means parallelism. Most likely if you are running a "simple" python script and are not aware of having played with threads, you are running on the main thread already. The question is open if you are integrated into a framework though.

Answer (score 1):

the waitKey() part should not depend on the validity of the frame, move it out of the condition:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cars.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #print frame.shape   

    if(ret): #if cam read is successfull
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    else:
        break

    # this should be called always, frame or not.
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still got the same result. The window froze after the video ended.

Comment: I notice that if the "else" statement is placed after the last "if" statement then the video does not play at all. I just see the window pop up and show a frame and close quickly. It happens fast. I guess only one frame got played. Why is that?

Comment: Because your code is then saying `if 'q': break  else: break` which means it can't loop at all.